# Lifting then cardio or vice versa for better fat burning?

Tags: weight-loss

I want to lose fat because I'm overweight. My excercise routine at the gym involves lifting and cardio. But I always wonder, which one to do first? Should I do lifting and then cardio or the opposite? And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am in the same boat and after much research I have found that...

if your more concerned about fat loss do cardio first as you will be to tired after lifting if you do lifting first and cut your cardio workout short... cardio first is also good for warming up the muscle & getting blood into it.

if your more concerned about gaining muscle, do cardio after as it will give you more energy to complete your lifting routine 100%, also more growth hormone is let off when cardio is done after.

However I have also read that cardio first also increases growth hormone and your body temp is heightened when lifting, so either way... not really much difference... but I would recommend cardio first :)